# Where to put local movie files for Kodi on Retropie?

Tags: retropie

I have Retropie on a Raspberry 3B+ and Kodi installed on top of Retropie. Both are latest as of Nov 12 2020. The SD card (64GB) has plenty of extra space, so I would like to put some movies in there for local (i.e. internet-less) watching using Kodi.

Here is a snapshot of the folders:

[image]

Are there somewhere I should put these movies? (Are there forbidden locations where I cannot put the movie files?) I'm not familiar with how files are organized in a Linux system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Pi specific Question, but a general Linux Question.

The ONLY existing directories you should use are `home` or `var`.

Kodi may have its own ideas of where files should be stored, if so use that, otherwise use a directory in your `home`, although you could create a new directory under `/` if there are multiple users.

If you are planning on a lot of files most Linux users would create a new partition, but this is a little more fiddly on a Pi SD Card.

Comment: I will create /home/movies then. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to change that location to /home/$USER/movies  in my case as the user pi, it would be "mkdir /home/pi/movies"